# i2c slave write and read from memory locations in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, i2c, vivado

I'm trying to implement I²C slave with write and read operations(8 bit data), and in my code write part is working fine and on the read side the data needs to be read is not coming properly, I mean its all "11111111"'s.

In read part its getting the slave address and after that instead of writing register number from which I need to read from, it shows all "11111111"s. I need a help on that. And the both write and read should happen to from 256 register locations. How to write and read a data on the registers?

Here in my code I just try to implement some registers instead of using all 256 I just used 10 registers. And I need some suggestions on that to do so.

I'm using Artix-7 Digilent Basys 3 board and Vivado 2016.4. Here's my code and simulation results.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity I2C is

  Port (clk : in std_logic;
        rst : in std_logic;
        ena : in std_logic;
        rw  : in std_logic;
        state_cnt : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        data_read : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        sda : inout std_logic;
        scl : out std_logic );

end I2C;

architecture Behavioral of I2C is

type machine is (ready,start,slave_addr,slv_ack1,reg_num,act_data,read_data,slv_ack2,mas_ack,stop,slv_ack3);
signal pre_state,next_state : machine;

signal data_clk : std_logic;
signal scl_clk : std_logic;
signal scl_ena : std_logic := '0';
signal sda_int : std_logic := '1';
signal sda_ena : std_logic;
signal addr_rw : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal data_tx : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal data_rx : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal bit_count : integer range 0 to 7 := 7;

signal addr : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0) := "1010000";
signal data_wr : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "01010110";--"11110000";
--signal data_rd : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "01010110";
signal wr_addr : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00000001"; 
signal count : integer range 0 to 250;

type slv_array is array (0 to 9) of std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
signal reg_array : slv_array;

begin

reg_array(0) <= "00000000";
reg_array(1) <= "00000001";
reg_array(2) <= "00000010";
reg_array(3) <= "00000011";
reg_array(4) <= "00000100";
reg_array(5) <= "00000101";
reg_array(6) <= "00000110";
reg_array(7) <= "00000111";
reg_array(8) <= "00001000";
reg_array(9) <= "00001001";

process (clk, rst)
begin
    if (rst = '1') then
        count <= 0;
     elsif (rising_edge(clk))then
        if (count = 249) then
--            temp <= not temp;
            count <= 0;
        else
            count <= count + 1;
        end if;
        end if;
end process;
--scl_clk <= temp;
process (clk,rst,count) 
begin
    if (rst = '1') then
        scl_clk <= '0';
        data_clk <= '0';
     elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
        case count is 
            when 0 to 62 =>
                scl_clk <= '0';
                data_clk <= '0';

            when 63 to 124 =>
                scl_clk <= '0';
                data_clk <= '1';

            when 125 to 187 =>
                scl_clk <= '1';
                data_clk <= '1';

            when 188 to 249 =>
                scl_clk <= '1';
                data_clk <= '0';

            when others => null;
        end case;
    end if;
end process;

process (clk,rst)
begin
    if (rst = '1') then
        pre_state  <= ready;
     elsif (rising_edge(clk))then
        pre_state <= next_state;
    end if;
end process;

process(data_clk,rst)
begin
    if (rst = '1') then
        next_state <= ready;
        scl_ena <= '0';
        sda_int <= '1';
        bit_count <= 7;
        data_read <= "00000000";
        state_cnt <= "1111";
      elsif (rising_edge(data_clk)) then
        case pre_state is
            when ready =>
                state_cnt <= "0001";
                if (ena ='1') then
                    addr_rw <= addr & rw;
                    data_tx <= wr_addr;  
                    next_state <= start;
                else                 
                    next_state <= ready;
                end if;

            when start =>
                state_cnt <= "0010";
                scl_ena <= '1';
                sda_int <= addr_rw(bit_count);
                next_state <= slave_addr;

            when slave_addr =>
                state_cnt <= "0011";
                if (bit_count = 0) then
                    sda_int <= '1';
                    bit_count <= 7;
                    next_state <= slv_ack1;
                else
                    bit_count <= bit_count - 1;
                    sda_int <= addr_rw(bit_count -1);
                    next_state <= slave_addr;
                end if;

            when slv_ack1 =>
                state_cnt <= "0100";
                if (addr_rw(0) = '0') then
                    sda_int <= data_tx(bit_count);
                    next_state <= reg_num;
                else
                    sda_int <= '1';
                    next_state <= read_data; 
                end if;

            when reg_num =>
                state_cnt <= "0101";
                if (bit_count = 0) then
                    sda_int <= '1';
                    bit_count <= 7;
                    next_state <= slv_ack2;
                else
                    bit_count <= bit_count - 1;
                    sda_int <= data_tx(bit_count -1);
                    next_state <= reg_num;
                end if;

            when slv_ack2 =>
                state_cnt <= "0110";
                if (ena ='1') then
                    data_tx <= data_wr;
                    sda_int <= data_wr(bit_count);  
                    next_state <= act_data;
                else
                    scl_ena <= '0';
                    next_state <= stop;  
                end if;

            when act_data =>
                state_cnt <= "0111";
                    if (bit_count =0) then
                        sda_int <= '1';
                        bit_count <= 7;
                        next_state <= slv_ack3;  
                    else
                        bit_count <= bit_count - 1;
                        sda_int <= data_tx(bit_count-1);
                        next_state <= act_data;
                    end if;

            when slv_ack3 =>
                state_cnt <= "1000";
                scl_ena <= '0';
                next_state <= stop;

           when stop =>
               state_cnt <= "1001";
                    if (rw = '1') then
                        next_state <= ready;  
                    else
                        next_state <= stop;
                    end if;


            when read_data =>
                state_cnt <= "1010"; 
                    if (bit_count = 0) then
                        if (ena ='1' and rw ='1') then
                            sda_int <= '0';
                        else
                            sda_int <= '1';
                        end if;

                        data_read(0) <= sda;
                        data_read(7 downto 1) <= data_rx(7 downto 1); 
                        bit_count <= 7;
                        next_state <= stop; 
                    else
                        data_rx(bit_count) <= sda;
                        bit_count <= bit_count - 1;
                        next_state <= read_data;
                    end if;    

            when mas_ack => 
                state_cnt <= "1011";
                    if (ena = '1') then
                        addr_rw <= addr & rw;
                        data_tx <= data_wr;
                            if (rw = '0') then
                                next_state <= start;
                            else
                                sda_int <= '1';
                                next_state <= read_data;
                            end if;
                    else
                        scl_ena <='0';
                        next_state <= stop;
                    end if;

            when others => null;
        end case;    
    end if;
end process;


WITH pre_state select 
    sda_ena <= data_clk when start,
               not data_clk when stop,
               sda_int when others;

    scl <= scl_clk; 
    sda <= '0' when sda_ena = '0' else sda_ena;                               


end Behavioral;
```

**I²C write:**
[image: I2C write]
(click to enlarge)

**I²C read:**
[image: I2C Read]
(click to enlarge)

Answer (score 0):

Care to show your testbench?

You have a problem with SDA line connection. If this core is inferior to your desing, you should use differend SDA_IN and SDA_OUT signals, and multiplex them into a single bidirectional line at the top level. If this file is a toplevel itself, you should set SDA  to 'Z', not to '0' when transmission is inactive to make this pin input during that time.

As for register connections, there are multiple ways to do so. For example, you can make i2c-controlled state machine, and use 1st opcode as a register number, and second one as a data for both reading and writing.

And you're using data_clk unbuffered signal as a clock. This is considered as a bad practice for FPGA. You should feed all your registers/processes with a single high-speed clock, and use enable signals to perform at lower speeds. Or feed your data_clk as a clock, but route ot via global clock buffer first.